# When does Dark Mode come to Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, meta, dark-mode

Since Dark Mode has been rolled out to Stack Overflow and the international SO sites, it's only been allowed on the main sites.  Why isn't it available on the meta sites?  Is the code/style sheet not similar enough to the main sites?

Comment: i can't stand the dark mode for this side.

Comment: Agreed; it's not enjoyable to browse SO and then click a link to Meta only to be blinded by a wall of bright white.

Comment: My eyes hurt when I look at meta to be honest. The sites CSS is somewhat similar, but a dev would really know exactly how hard it could be.

Comment: @TemaniAfif some people just want to watch the world b̶u̶r̶n̶ black.

Comment: Just have a pair of sunglasses handy for when you open meta. That is actually only half a joke; recently I started to use zero strength glasses with a blue light filter and that slightly darkens what you see, enough that bright sites no longer bother me.

Comment: I see a meta and I want to paint it black. No Firefoxes because I have to use some crap. I see the Firefoxes walk by dressed in their [dark mode skins](https://www.techradar.com/how-to/how-to-enable-dark-mode-for-firefox). I have to turn my head back to Internet Explorer 6.

Comment: @VLAZ I guess you could say some people just don't want to watch the world at all

Comment: I've taken to using a css injector with several sites I visit regularly. Meta is infinitely less scorching with just a couple of tag overrides. I've set `background` to #222222 and the `color` to #8888888. There's a couple more tags to change, but it only took a couple seconds to fix those.

Comment: I use DarkReader to turn sites without dark mode dark. Since SO has dark mode, it's one of the sites that I keep as an exception so it uses the native colours. Unfortunately, SO meta, being a subdomain, falls under that exception, so I'm greeted with a wall of white when I come here. It would be great if dark mode was implemented here sooner, rather than later.

Comment: In the mean time others can install this extension which solved this issue for me: [Stylus extension](https://github.com/openstyles/stylus)

Comment: Now it's May '22 and we're still waiting...

Comment: Now it's Aug '22 and some of us are still waiting because DarkReader, which can be configured to work only for meta so, is not much better than no DarkReader at all.

Comment: Nov '14 22 and I still lose my eyesight every time I open meta

Comment: Its Feb 2023. Any update on this issue please?

Comment: Related: [Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399/997587) and [my userscript there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385509/997587)

Answer (score -4):

Related feature-request for all Stack Exchange sites: [Dark Mode for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111399/997587) and [my userscript there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385509/997587). <sup><sub>I'd inline the content of the userscript, but I'm too lazy to maintain it inline in two places, and I think it's fair to ignore the in-another-castle rule for a link to MSE.</sub></sup>